# Finding the documentation for parsing data found in BLE Advertising Respones

Tags: parsing, bluetooth-lowenergy

### This is not a programming related question. It's a question about where to find the right documentation.

*If this is not the right place to ask, please let me know and I'll move the question*

---

I'm working on a C++-Deamon for parsing recieved *BLE Advertising Packages* (like `hcidump` from [bleuz](http://www.bluez.org/)). For this I'm focusing on parsing only *LE Advertising Report events* ([Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) 7.7.65.2, S. 2382 *ff*)

E. g: I need to extract the *local name* and the *16-bit UUID*. This information can be found (if broadcasted) in the field "data".

I can extract the data part from the *Advertising Event Packet* (since it's described in the Core Specification how these packages are arranged) but I can't parse the data. **I wasn't able to find a description of the codes used in this data frame**.

I also went through the [Core Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/), but I couldn’t find the corresponding codes. I only found some examples:

- See Site 26: Apparently the byte `0x09` indicates that the following *n* bytes are the broadcasted name of the BLE-Device.
- Or Site 25: `0x03` seems to indicate that a "Complete list of 16-bit Service UUIDs" is following.

So far I gained my knowledge about this by just going throught these (incomplete) list of examples I found and from looking at the source code of *hcidump.c*.

#### Now the question is: Where can I find the official complete list to those bytes/codes?

---

Just an example of the package content I revieve:

```
Respone: 04 3E 1C 02 01 04 01 55 19 19 E4 8D FE 10 0F 09 54 65 73 74 
  20 49 50 53 50 20 6E 6F 64 65 C5
```

It should be able to extract the following data

```
HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 28
    LE Advertising Report
      SCAN_RSP - Scan Response (4)
      bdaddr FE:8D:E4:19:19:55 (Random)
      Complete local name: 'Test IPSP node'
      RSSI: -61
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going throught the whole Bluetooth SIG, I finally found the site where these codes are described:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/